# Create a similar GPUImageToneCurveFilter with Metal in Swift 3

Tags: swift, video, filter, photoshop, metal

I have a big challenge with Metal. Basically, I want to to read .acv files from Photoshop and process a video with it in Metal. I've made some researches and found out that GPUImageToneCurveFilter, from GPUImage, perform the same thing I want but with images only.

In other words, I want to create custom filters with Photoshop, export it in .acv file extension and use in my app's video.

I really don't know where to start and how to do it. I would really appreciate if anyone could help find a get started tutorial in deep video processing with Metal and also how to understand shaders.

I'm already reading some articles about video processing with Metal and at the same time trying to understand GPUImageToneCurveFilter core.

Thank you for the support!